# Error:[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "react" from "resources\js\components..".Does the file exist? laravel10 vite react plugin

Tags: reactjs, vite, laravel-10

I want to using `react` on `laravel10`, and also I'm new on 'vitejs/plugin-react',

At first after create a react component shown this error:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "react/jsx-dev-runtime" from "resources\js\components\Example.jsx". Does the file exist?
```

then after adding this code.

`{jsxRuntime: 'classic'}`

to

`vite.config.js`,

error changed to this:

`[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "react" from "resources\js\components\Example.jsx". Does the file exist?`

I was doing any way to solve that but did not works.
my files is:
Example.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/client';

export default function Save(){
    return(
        <h1>Salam</h1>
    );
}
const container=document.getElementById("root");
const root=ReactDom.createRoot(container);
root.render(<Save />);
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react({jsxRuntime: 'classic'}),
    ],
});
```

app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';
import './components/Example';
```

blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    @viteReactRefresh
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>
</html>
```

Completely I have no idea about that.

`node_modules` is exists.

Ran `cmd` by administrator.

Removing the project and installing several time.